# Marlin 1.1.8 on Geeetech A10 - G0 and G1 ignores coordinates, always runs to [0, -6, 0]

Tags: marlin, geeetech

I've just gotten my Geeetech A10. I have a 3dTouch sensor installed. I got my offset and calibration set.

If I send a G1 or G0 command, regardless of arguments, it runs the print head off the front left of the bed [0,-6, 0]. I can send a G28 and it returns to the middle of the bed pretty much as expected.

For instance - I send G0 X10 Y10, it still runs to that same [0,-6, 0] position. Attempting to print anything is a no-go because every G1 or G0 sends it running back to that spot to spit filament off the edge of the bed.

I've rebuilt firmware from Geeetech's linked sources twice. Everything works with control from the dial, it just doesn't interpret G-code in any useful way.

Comment: Hi Kyle, and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! What an unusual problem, are you sure the sources are correct? Maybe try another firmware. Please update your question with a link to the sources.

Comment: Help us help you! Give us as much info as possible! For example a link to the firmware. Do you run Relative or Absolute coordinates? (G90 vs G91) Also very helpful would be to show us what M503 gives as an output when connected.. http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M503.html

Comment: Hi Kyle, does your control software or printer display [0, -6, 0]?  As Trish said, have you tested sending commands with relative vs absolute coordinates?